# Update column values with splited values

Tags: sql, split, sql-update

I have a sql table `Product`:

```
id name value   type
1  a    abs#123  1
2  b    abs#123  2
3  c    abs#123  1
```

How can I update the value column for the products type 1 with the value before `#` , meaning that `abs#123` will be `abs`, so I have to split the value column by `#`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Left` and `charindex` function. Try this.

```
update Product 
set value=left(value,charindex('#',value)-1)
where type=1
```

or use `Substring`

```
update Product 
set value=substring(value,1,charindex('#',value)-1)
where type=1
```